# What is the purpose of 'LIMIT 0,1' on this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following an API tutorial (user authentication), but i'm fairly new to SQL, so there are some stuff that i dont understand.
I've been looking for an answer and as far as i know, the LIMIT clause has an offset (0 in this case) and a count (1 in this case).
This is the code (inside the user class):

```
function emailExists(){

    // query to check if email exists
    $query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, password
            FROM " . $this->table_name . "
            WHERE email = ?
            LIMIT 0,1";

    // prepare the query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // sanitize
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

    // bind given email value
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->email);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get number of rows
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    // if email exists, assign values to object properties for easy access and use for php sessions
    if($num>0){

        // get record details / values
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // assign values to object properties
        $this->id = $row['id'];
        $this->firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $this->lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $this->password = $row['password'];

        // return true because email exists in the database
        return true;
    }

    // return false if email does not exist in the database
    return false;
}
```

What i understand is that the query starts looking for a similar email from the start (row 0), but then i don't understand why they bind the 1 to the email.

Is it necessary to use a LIMIT here? why can't just use the clause WHERE email = :email (and bind the :email to the email sent by the user?)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: BTW this does not sanitize `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));`. It prepares the string for output into HTML, which makes no sense in the place where you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query checks whether email exists only. If there is more records with the same email it takes more resources to execute statement. If there is at least one record it means email exists. No need to check more.

This case doesn't show it clearly but imagine you have table with millions of records and you want to check whether one specific value exists which can appear in multiple records. You can freeze database if query is too complicated /too many tables are joint etc. You need only to check, so you limit it to 1. This is nice practice to this type of queries.